# Why is a promise rejection within a loop not handled in a try catch in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

If I have a promise rejection within a for that is not caught by a try/catch surrounding the for or the invoker method catch block

```
const asyncMethod = async (item) => {
  return Promise.reject(item);
};

const sleep = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

const myMethod = async () => {
  try {
    const myArr = [1, 2,];
    
    const promises = [];

    for (const item of myArr) {
      const myPromise = asyncMethod(item);
      promises.push(myPromise);
      await sleep(1);
    }

    await Promise.allSettled(promises);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('handled by try catch');
  }
};

myMethod().catch(() => {
  console.log('handled by invoker');
});
```

If I run this i will get unhandled rejection, and I'm wondering why is it not hitting my catch block.

I'm not asking for a solution, I'm just trying to understand how V8 works.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't just V8 - *any* spec-compliant implementation will produce an unhandled rejection with this code.

At the moment that a Promise rejects, there must be a `.catch` handler *somewhere* that has been attached to the Promise to catch the rejection. Otherwise, an unhandled rejection will occur - the engine can't look into the future to see if you attach a handler at a later time, it must be seen as attached *right* when the Promise rejects.

Because you do

```
  const myPromise = asyncMethod(item);
  promises.push(myPromise);
  await sleep(1);
```

You're waiting for `sleep` *before* passing the promise that will reject to `.allSettled` (which will count as a rejection handler). If the Promise rejects before all the `sleep`s finish, there'll be an unhandled rejection.

(`.allSettled` *does* count as a reject handler, as you can see below:)

```js
const asyncMethod = async (item) => {
  return Promise.reject(item);
};

const sleep = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

const myMethod = async () => {
  try {
    const myArr = [1, 2,];
    
    const promises = [];

    for (const item of myArr) {
      const myPromise = asyncMethod(item);
      promises.push(myPromise);
      // dummy rejection handler through .allSettled attached immediately, just to illustrate:
      Promise.allSettled([myPromise]);
      await sleep(1);
    }

    await Promise.allSettled(promises);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('handled by try catch');
  }
};

myMethod().catch(() => {
  console.log('handled by invoker');
});
```

Comment: I see, I need to attach a handler immediately. I thought the the try/catch would catch it but it makes sense, it just goes unhandled.

Comment: I wouldn't (ab)use `Promise.allSettled` for this. Better write `myPromise.catch(_ => {/* later */});`.

Comment: Yep, it's `// ... just to illustrate:`